# I do not understand error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

Why do i get error 1004 here:

```
ILast = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

I tried

```
Sheets("MFG_DATA").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

And then I get error 9.

This is the loop it is in,

```
With DCSPROGRAM.Sheets("MFG_DATA")
   ILast = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
      For i = 1 To ILast
      If .Cells(i, 1).Value = MFG Then
         FORM.Cells(8, 2) = .Cells(i, 3).Value
```

I have a loop very similar to it and it does not trigger error 1004:

```
    With Wbk.Sheets("QTR_LOG")
    ILast = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To ILast
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = QTR_NUM Then
            .Cells(i, 6) = TOTALFOB
            .Cells(i, 7) = TOTALWC
            .Cells(i, 10) = TOTALTIME
```

Comment: The second error is caused probably because the workbook which contains sheet ```MFG_DATA``` was not active at the time when the code was executed. Solution: use fully qualified names of sheets, ranges, cells. See e.g. [this](http://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-object-model/#object-references-fully-qualified-references-and-connecting-vba-objects) article for more informations.

Comment: Looks like a great article and something that i have been missing. I started with VBA for dummies and then kinda just hit the ground running. Now im starting to see leaks in my understanding. Looks like its study time. Thanks Again for the article, @dee

Comment: Referencing using not-fully qualified names is common source of errors in VBA ... but don't worry you will learn it :). Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is **DCSPROGRAM** an XLS with a maximum of 65,536 rows in its worksheets? If you are running code from an XLSX then `Rows.Count` means 1,048,576. Try is as,

```
With DCSPROGRAM.Sheets("MFG_DATA")
    ILast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ...
End With
```

Note the `.` in `.Rows.Count`. This means the count of the rows in that worksheet, not one picked out of the air from any worksheet.

Comment: DCSPROGRAM is a .XLSM. It is a workbook with several sheets with specific names. I will see if this works with .xlsm. I also need to learn more about correct formatting =) Thanks @Jeeped